# passing response object from java to javafx.( Desktop application )

Tags: java, javafx

Im am planning on creating a desktop application with JavaFX. I would like to use JavaFX only for the UI, and all backend work should be done by java(with spring).Im not sure how to develop the frontend to call the service layer, and also receive the response and display the response on the next page.

Basically I need to know the following(just an example of want i want to accomplish).

1) to call the controller class I would do something like below in 'Login.fx'?

```
function btnLoginAction(): Void {
    var loginController = LoginController {};
    loginController.authenticateUser(txtboxUsername.text.trim(),  pwdboxPassword.text.trim());
}
```

2) LoginController would be my java class and would call the service layer. after authentication, i would want to call another page('Welcome.fx') and pass the firstname of the logged-in user as a parameter. How do I accomplish this?

Im new to javafx(java gui development as a whole), hence let me know if there is a better approach to go about this, and some links to help me better understand.

NOTE: I am using javafx 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use java classes from javafx, e.g. the way you suggested is correct.
2. To achieve that you can just add a parameter to Welcome class and set it during creation/accessing with value received from LoginController instance.

P.S.: but I really suggest you to move to JavaFX 2.0. JavaFX 1.3 script language is not supported unfortunately, so no new functionality would be accessible.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Few questions regarding (2). How do I call the 'Welcome.fx'. any code example showing this.  I do know Javafx 2.0 can be used, but i needed to make a quick demo app, and the javafx composer is quiet helpful in 1.3. I didnt try figuring out the fxml, even though I know that may be easier. I just like the composer.

Comment: smth like `var name:String=loginController.getName(); var welcomePage = Welcome { welcomeName = name };` (not sure about fx script grammar)